# Shoes Debian package

Tags: shoes

Does anyone know of a Debian Package of Shoes?

I am building a live CD and would like to include shoes in it, but I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://packages.debian.org/testing/interpreters/shoes

Comment: Thanks, I'm a Ubuntu noob, so I have a follow up question.

How do I use that from within the Ubuntu Customization Kit (UCK Package Manager)?

Comment: got it, just had to use edit->search so that I could find the package from the UCK Package Manager

Answer (score 1):

[packages.debian.org/search?keywords=shoes](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=shoes)

Paket shoes

- [lenny (stable)](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/shoes) (interpreters): tiny graphics and windowing toolkit using Ruby 
  0.r396-5: alpha amd64 arm armel hppa i386 ia64 mips mipsel powerpc s390 sparc
- [squeeze (testing)](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/shoes) (interpreters): tiny graphics and windowing toolkit using Ruby 
  0.r396-5: alpha amd64 armel hppa i386 ia64 mips mipsel powerpc s390 sparc
- [sid (unstable)](http://packages.debian.org/sid/shoes) (interpreters): tiny graphics and windowing toolkit using Ruby 
  0.r396-5: alpha amd64 armel hppa hurd-i386 i386 ia64 m68k mips mipsel powerpc s390 sparc